# Julia Tk: prevent script exit

Tags: tk-toolkit, julia

How does one write a Julia script which creates a Tk GUI and then persists until the user exits the program?

My issue is that my scripts terminate, causing any windows I have created to also terminate. I would like to do something such that my code keeps on running until I close the window (or press escape or something). Is there a good way to do this? The examples provided with Tk assume you are using the REPL.

Calling sleep() kind of works, but is not a good solution. Is there a recommended solution that is better than:

```
done = false
while !done
    sleep(1)
    done = check_if_done(...)
end
```

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using tk or gtk? Your question mentions tk, but you accepted an answer related to gtk.

Comment: The tk style would be `tcl("tkwait", "window", w)` where `w` is a `Toplevel` window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even better is

```
if !isinteractive()
    wait(Condition())
end
```

so that if you're running the script from the REPL, you won't have to hit CTRL-C.

This is a general solution (it doesn't really use the graphical toolkit), although jverzani points out above that there's a good Tk-based solution.

Answer (score 2):

from:  https://github.com/JuliaLang/Gtk.jl/issues/38

Call ''wait(Condition())" at the end of you script to prevent termination

(also some other advice/discussion on that page)

Comment: It works, and I can specify the condition function myself, which is great. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding the following code to the end?

```
set_visible(w, true);
```

compare with:  http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Hello_world/Graphical#Julia

Comment: Nope, this has exactly the same problem. They even have sleep() on the last line commented out so you know you can use it if you are running it outside of the REPL